# Permanent magnet generator tooth width

Tags: generator, electromagnetic, magnet

I am thinking about designing a radial flux permanent magnet generator. However, I could not find any information about determining the tooth width. Should the tooth width be all the way the same as the magnet width, or can it be thicker? [image]

So I am interested in lt and lv relation.

Comment: teeth should not be wider than the magnet spacing, having tooth spacing the same as magnet spacing is required if you're making a single phase generator.

Comment: Thanks! By magnet spacing, you mean the spaces between magnets or the length of magnets? What changes in case of a three phase generator?

Comment: length of magnets, or distance centre to centre.

Answer (score 1):

For the best design, permanent magnets fastened to the surface of a generator rotor would likely emulate the construction of a wound field synchronous generator. The same would likely be true for the stator design.

In a salient-pole, wound-field synchronous machine, the most satisfactory pole embrace is about 70 to 72 percent. The stator windings are distributed in slots with a certain number of slots per phase per pole. Slots are evenly distributed around the entire circumference of the stator with no unused slots between poles.

The air gap between a pole shoe and the stator iron is smallest at center and somewhat larger at the edges with the edges rounded at the edge.